# Combining Two Functions that Build Two Separate Arrays

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been working on this script for two weeks now and can't figure it out. I think I need to combine these two functions to create one array and use the getSheetNames() function to be more of a descriptor. Then I want to run a separate function to filter the array into two different sheets on a master document based on sheet name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Function to pull all data from workbook
function getDataFromSpreadsheet1(ssID) {
  
  //Open workbook
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  //Get all sheets in workbook and put into array
  let data = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getRange(4, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, 3).getValues()).flat(1);
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;
  
}

//Function to return name of sheets in workbook
function getSheetNames(ssID) {

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let session = [];
  sheets.forEach(function (sheet) { 
    session.push(sheet.getName());
  });
  Logger.log(session);
  return session;

}
```

Comment: After researching arrays further, I think I want the array to be structured kind of like this if possible: [ [ [session][data] ] [ [session][data] ] ] etc.

Comment: getSheetNames(ssID) getDataFromSpreadsheet1(ssID).  does these 2 ssID the same one?

Comment: The variable ssID is the same but I'm pulling from 40 different work books so they differ depending on the file. I have a while loop further up that is looping through the workbooks.

Comment: Let me know if I'm wrong.     You are going to get sheet name and values, then turn them into an array [ [ [sheet1 name], [sheet1 data]  ] , [ [sheet2 name], [sheet2 data]  ]  ], correct?

Comment: @liquidkat yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

#### Combining multiple Sheets of multiple spreadsheets

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet1(ssID) {
  const ssids = ['ssID1', 'ssID2'];
  data = []
  ssids.forEach(ssid => {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
    let vs = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getRange(4, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, 3).getValues()).flat(1);
    data.push(vs)
  })
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

[flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

[array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet1(ssID) {

  //Open workbook
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  //Get all sheets in workbook and put into array
  let data = ss.getSheets().map(sh =>{
        return [[sh.getName()],sh.getRange(4, 1, 3, 3).getValues().flat(1)]
  });

  console.log(data);
  return data;

}
```

Comment: I actually combined your suggestion and @Copper suggestion and it worked! Now I need to figure out how to sort this data and only print the one array to the sheet, if possible.

Comment: what do you mean print array to the sheet?   You mean set the values?

Comment: Yes, this is a part of a large master google sheet project. I have about 40 workbooks each with two sheets of data. I need to pull all data from the sheets and sort it into a master workbook. I'm looking to use the array we assigned the sheet name as the descriptor to then sort the data onto the appropriate sheet.

Comment: how do you determine which array goes to where? What's the key? Now you have the data you need. Then you have to assign these data into different sheet or into one sheet. Ritfgt?

Comment: The sheet names need to correlate to a specific sheet on the master workbook. I think I need some kind of loop to sort through the arrays, read the sheet name, pop the sheet array so the sheet name doesn't appear in the master and then write the corresponding data to the correct sheet in the master.